# Save Files to Owner G-Drive(Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, publish, google-workspace

I have a **web app** created using **google script** which is **distributed** in a team,They will use it to **upload some files**.

I want to save those files into my **drive rather than their own accounts**.

According to my research I can only save it my account If I publish that app with option **Execute as me** and option who has **access with anonymous**.

But I want to Execute as **user accessing this app option(that required user to authorized).**

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a service account and enable [Domain-wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) on it. Then you can execute saves to the Google Drive under your account. You'll need to leverage a Google OAuth2 library.

Here's a good one:

[OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2)